# Can't get into Google Analytics without going into incognito

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics

When I try to access analytics.google.com in standard Chrome browser, I get this error:

> Missing permissions You do not have access to the account, property,
>   or view. Contact an Analytics administrator who has the Manage Users
>   permission.
>   [image]

If I use incognito, I can get in just fine.

Tried clearing Cache and cookies, no help.

Any thoughts on what the problem is?

Comment: I get this too in Chrome, when Chrome autofills the URL. If I knock the URL back to just analytics.google.com, I get in fine. Try it.

Comment: Nope, still no go.  )=

Comment: Sorry! I am afraid I'm stuck now.

Comment: Same issue here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try disabling your Chrome extensions.
In my case uBlock was causing this issue.

Comment: How could I not have tried that? I swear I did. Oh well, I see it works when I disable uBlock! Thanks!

Comment: Not helped, I don't have any chrome extension

Comment: Many years later, just wanted to say thanks. Saved my bacon!

Answer (score 2):

The funny thing is : this is solved by **restarting chrome**. if not you can try to **restart your PC** (assuming you don't have any other blocking chrome plugins).

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same error but I was trying to access the Google Analytics property from the Firebase > Project Settings > Integration > Google Analytics. None of the solutions listed here worked. I ended up unlinking the Google Analytics and linking a new one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove Honey to fix the issue. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your AdBlocker on, disable it. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, turning off PC Matic Ad blocker fixed it for me.

Comment: There is already a community accepted answer, this may be a comment there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was the URL - it was an old one straight to some GA screen. Using the root GA URL works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Click on "All Website Data" in the top menu. See whether you have chosen the correct domain. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled the Chrome Extension "Google Docs Offline" and its working fine now. Try disabling your Chrome Extensions one by one and refresh google analytics page.